# Segmentation fault on class when declared as pointer

Tags: c++, templates

So I’m in the process of creating an event style system, but this code breaks when I declare a connection as a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono_literals;

template<typename... Types>
struct Connection {
    
    void Connect(void(*f)(Types...)) {
        Callback = f;
    }
    
    void Fire(Types... Args) {
        Callback(Args...);
    }
    
private:
    void(*Callback)(Types...);
};

int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;
    
    Connection<char>* event;
    
    event->Connect([](char key){
        cout << "Event fired!" << '\n';
        cout << "Key: " << key << '\n';
    });
    
    event->Fire('a');
}
```

This code works when the connection isn’t a pointer, and instead of using the `->`  operator, I’d use use the regular `.`  operator, but I’d like to declare them as pointers so I can use the `->` .

One very strange thing to note is when I do something like this

```
Connection<char> e;
Connection<char>* event;

// ... rest of code
```

Then this actually runs, I don’t know why it’s like that.

Comment: For `event->Connect(...)` to be valid, `event` has to point to an existing object, otherwise you get undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can have any weird effect, including being fixed by adding an unrelated variable.

Comment: Just change `Connection<char>* event;` to `Connection<char> event;` and `event->` to `event.`. Yet another example of the needless use of pointers.

Comment: "but I’d like to declare them as pointers so I can use the -> " ... hum thats odd motivation. You do not necessarily need a pointer to use `->`, you can first get adress of an object then use `->` to dereference. In any case you need an object, a pointer is just a pointer

Comment: why do you think `->` has an advantage over `.` ?

Comment: This is gonna sound really dumb, but because it looks nicer. My code runs when I just use a regular object.

Comment: not "dumb" at all, but misguided and confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't "declare a class as a pointer". That's not a thing. You have a class (which is a type), then you declare an *instance* of that class (i.e. an object). Optionally you can manage that object using pointers.

But you didn't actually create any instance. All you did was create a pointer, uninitialised, not pointing to anything, then tried to dereference it to use the object it points to… which doesn't exist.

There's no need for dynamic allocation here anyway; forget the pointer and just declare a nice `Connection<Event>`. Using pointers "because it looks nicer" is, to put it kindly, not the best way to write a C++ program.